# Which TeX distribution? (Undefined control sequence)

Tags: texlive, document-classes

(FYI I am new to LaTeX)

I'm trying to compile a TeX document that someone else has given me. I had BasicTex installed, and it didn't seem to work. My friend said he uses TeX Live, so I tried installing that but I get the same error after typing `pdftex document.tex`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  [final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
```

I'm guessing that means the distribution I have installed does not support this tag, is that right?  How can I find out which distribution I should install?

Comment: Use `pdflatex document.tex` not `pdftex`.

Comment: I just wanted to note that BasicTeX is TeXLive.

Comment: Since you are new to LaTeX, you should read the [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your document is a LaTeX document, not plain TeX. Use the `pdflatex` command on it.